# automatically save custom post type title as a category

Tags: custom-post-types, categories

I wonder if there is a way to automatically create category from my custom post type titles.
For example - if I create post named 'sport', the function will create a category - 'sport' automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hook into save_post, and check if the category already exists (to avoid double creation on post edit). If category doesn't exist create it using [`wp_insert_term`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_term) and assign to post using [`wp_set_object_terms`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_object_terms)

```
add_action('save_post', 'add_title_as_category');

function add_title_as_category( $postid ) {
  if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;
  $post = get_post($postid);
  if ( $post->post_type == 'post') { // change 'post' to any cpt you want to target
    $term = get_term_by('slug', $post->post_name, 'category');
    if ( empty($term) ) {
      $add = wp_insert_term( $post->post_title, 'category', array('slug'=> $post->post_name) );
      if ( is_array($add) && isset($add['term_id']) ) {
        wp_set_object_terms($postid, $add['term_id'], 'category', true );
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you want to set a custom taxonomy instead of the standard category replace `'category'` with the custom taxonomy name everywhereit appear in code above.

Comment: is there a way to do same thing to save specific post type (named 'groups')  titles in specific taxonomy (for exemple - save the page titles as a term in  taxonomy named 'genre')?

Comment: @NetShapira I've updated the answer to accomplish what you ask.

Comment: Thanks for the great code! Is it also possible to sync the post slugs with the category slug, so if I change the slug of the post the category slug also changes?